# javascript creating an object for my game OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm looking for some examples or sample code for properly organizing my code for my game.

I have a game:

```
var gameStructure = function () {
  this.playerLife = 100;
}
```

How do I create new game instances (since multiple games will be going on?)

```
var gameInstance = new gameStructure();
```

And how do I format the code for game actions?

```
var attackPlayer = function (damage) {
    this.playerLife = this.playerLife - damage;
}

gameInstance.attackPlayer(50);
```

This is not real code, I'm sure this is all wrong and not how you're supposed to do javascript code at all. One thing I'm confused on is how to create multiple gameInstances. I don't know how to set variables as variables.

I mean I need:

```
var gameInstance1
gameInstance2
```

etc, based on how many games players are in.

Right now I'm actually storing game instances in an array.

So I have:

```
var gameInstances = [], gameid

var createNewGame = function () {
  gameInstances.push(gameInstanceName);
  gameid = gameInstances.indexOf(gameInstanceName); 
}
```

and then i reference my game instance object by gameInstances[gameid].

Is there OK to do or is that inadvisable and I should use OOP with instantiation with the new keyword.

Thanks and please advised!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OOP equivalent in JavaScript would be attach the `attackPlayer` function to `gameStructure`'s `prototype`:

```
gameStructure.prototype.attackPlayer = function (damage) {
    this.playerLife = this.playerLife - damage;
};
```

All instances of `gameStructure` will inherit the `attackPlayer` function, and `this` will correctly reference the instance.

Your `createNewGame` function can simply call `new gameStructure()` and push the result onto an array. The `gameid` is just the index in the array, and can be returned from the function:

```
var gameInstances = [];

var createNewGame = function () {
    gameInstaces.push(new gameStructure());
    return gameInstances.length - 1;
};
```

---

With the above code, usage is as follows:

```
var gameId = createNewGame();
gameInstances[gameId].attackPlayer(100);
```

Comment: can you expand on your answer? How would I use the attackPlayer fucntion? THanks.

Comment: @FriiSource, I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use function like objects:

```
function Vector2(x, y) // Constructor
{
    // Member variable
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    Vector2.count++;

    // Member function
    this.length = function ()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
    }
}
// Static members
Vector2.count = 0;

// Static Functions
Vector2.add = function (a, b)
{
    // Instantiation
    return new Vector2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}


function Point(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Single Inheritance
Point.prototype = new Vector2();

Point.distanceBetween = function (a, b)
{
    var diff = new Vector2(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
    return diff.length();
}
```

The strangest thing about OOP stuff in Javascript is that the function it self is the constructor. I hope this helps.